# Google Api Chart Log Scale is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

I am using Google Api Charts. The bellow is my options for the Bar chart. The hAxis logarithmic scale is not working. If you have any questions regarding the code, please let me know.

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        title: '@Model.Title',
        subtitle: '@Model.SubTitle',

        vAxis: {
            minValue: 0.1,
            logScale: true,
            scaleType:"mirrorLog"
        }
    }
};
```

[Edited]

According to google's documentation, for the Axis there need to be **minValue**, **scaleType** and **ticks**. However, I changed as bellow but still it is not working.
I appreciate your feedback.

```
vAxis: {
    minValue: 0,
      scaleType: 'mirrorLog',
      ticks: [10, 20, 50, 80, 100]
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Material Bar Charts - The Material Charts are in beta. The appearance and interactivity are largely final, but many of the options available in Classic Charts are not yet available in them. You can find a list of options that are not yet supported in [this issue](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I suggest you to take a look at this content: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer